# Correo vacío con PHPMailer

Tags: php

Envío un correo con PHPMailer pero este llega totalmente vacío. ¿Cual es el problema? Mi código es el siguiente:

```
    <?php 

require('class.phpmailer.php');
require('vistas/mail.view.php');
//se instancia un objeto de la clase phpmailer
$mail=new PHPMailer();

    define("correo", "soporte1@farmaciassanasana.com.mx");
    define("farmacia", "Farmacias Sana Sana S.A DE C.V.");

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
        $de=filter_var($_POST['de'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $nombre=filter_var($_POST['nombre'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $asunto=filter_var($_POST['asunto'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $mensaje=filter_var($_POST['mensaje'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        //instancio un objeto de la clase PHPMailer
            $mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

            //defino el cuerpo del mensaje en una variable $body
            //se trae el contenido de un archivo de texto
            //también podríamos hacer $body="contenido...";
            $body = 'vistas/mail.view.php';
            //Esta línea la he tenido que comentar
            //porque si la pongo me deja el $body vacío
            // $body = preg_replace('/[]/i','',$body);

            //defino el email y nombre del remitente del mensaje
            $mail->SetFrom($de, $nombre);

            //defino la dirección de email de "reply", a la que responder los mensajes
            //Obs: es bueno dejar la misma dirección que el From, para no caer en spam
            $mail->AddReplyTo($de, $nombre);
            //Defino la dirección de correo a la que se envía el mensaje
            $address = correo;
            //la añado a la clase, indicando el nombre de la persona destinatario
            $mail->AddAddress($address, farmacia);

            //Añado un asunto al mensaje
            $mail->Subject = $asunto;

            //Puedo definir un cuerpo alternativo del mensaje, que contenga solo texto
            $mail->AltBody = $mensaje;

            //inserto el texto del mensaje en formato HTML
            $mail->MsgHTML($body);

            //asigno un archivo adjunto al mensaje
            //$mail->AddAttachment($adjunto);
            $mail->CharSet = "UTF­8";
            $mail->Encoding = "quoted­printable";

            //envío el mensaje, comprobando si se envió correctamente
            if(!$mail->Send()) {
            echo "Error al enviar el mensaje: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
            echo "Mensaje enviado!!";
            }
        }
 ?>
```

Comment: En el body del mensaje que recibes te llega como texto 'vistas/mail.view.php'?

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar una vista a tu body con contenido PHP deberia ser algo asi :

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body = get_include_contents('../vistas/mail.view.php', $data);
```

Debes pasarle el $data los valores que vas a mostrar en tu archivo `php`

Lo que haces tu es solo entregarle un valor `string` a body por eso jamas va a llegar algo distinto a lo que dejas entre `' '`

Answer (score 0):

`'vistas/mail.view.php'` no es un html válido, de echo es una cadena de caracteres por eso no pinta nada. Ahi debe ir un html y esto `$body='vistas/mail.view.php'` no lo incluye. Mejor declara una función en 'vistas/mail.view.php' que arme el html y te lo regreses como cadena y la llamas aqui `$body=funcionX();`